# How do I see all my databases for a particular server under one connection?

Tags: sql-server, database-connection, ssms

I am trying to read data from DB1, do some calculations on it and then store it in DB2. Both DB1 and DB2 are on the same server.

However, when I connect to the server on SSMS, it does not show me DB1 and DB2 under the same connection. How do I connect to the server such that it shows both DB1 and DB2 in the same connection?

Answer (score 0):

A connection can have only one database context. However, you can use 3-part names to qualify object names with other database names, allowing a query to use objects in other databases on the same connection.

```
USE Database1; --use Database1 as default context
SELECT 
      'Database1' AS DatabaseName
    , OBJECT_SCHEMA_NAME(object_id) AS SchemaName
    , name AS TableName
FROM sys.tables -- 1 or 2-part name uses current database
UNION ALL
SELECT
      'Database2' AS DatabaseName
    , OBJECT_SCHEMA_NAME(object_id) AS SchemaName
    , name AS TableName
FROM Database2.sys.tables; -- 3-part name uses other database
```

Also, 4-part names allow one to use objects on other servers via linked servers.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the help Dan - the 4-part naming did not work for me. Ended up creating an **external table** in DB2 which allowed me to query data stored in DB1